# Working with Embind, does a returned ClassHandle.delete() properly delete all the properties?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, embind

If emscripten/embind returns an object with a bunch of vector properties, do I need to call .delete() on each property, or can I just call .delete() on the returned object?

ie:  If I am returned an emscripten ClassHandle for RGB, do I need to call rgb.r.delete(), or does rgb.delete() handle that for me?

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>
using namespace emscripten;

class RGB {
public:
    std::vector<unsigned char> r;
    std::vector<unsigned char> g;
    std::vector<unsigned char> b;
    RGB (
        std::vector<unsigned char> r_ = std::vector<unsigned char>(0,0),
        std::vector<unsigned char> g_ = std::vector<unsigned char>(0,0),
        std::vector<unsigned char> b_ = std::vector<unsigned char>(0,0)
        ) {
        r = r_;
        g = g_;
        b = b_;
    }
};

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    class_<RGB>("RGB")
        .constructor<
            std::vector<unsigned char>,
            std::vector<unsigned char>,
            std::vector<unsigned char>
            >()
        .property("r", &RGB::r)
        .property("g", &RGB::g)
        .property("b", &RGB::b)
        ;
    register_vector<unsigned char>("Uint8Array");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Emscripten documentation [Memory Management](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#memory-management)

> **Warning**
>
> It is strongly recommended that JavaScript code explicitly deletes any
> C++ object handles it has received.
>
> The delete() JavaScript method is provided to manually signal that a
> C++ object is no longer needed and can be deleted:
>
> `var x = new Module.MyClass; x.method(); x.delete();`
>
> `var y = Module.myFunctionThatReturnsClassInstance(); y.method(); y.delete();`
>
> **Note**
>
> Both C++ objects constructed from the JavaScript side as well as those
> returned from C++ methods must be explicitly deleted.

```
var myclass = new Module.MyClass(); //Creates a C++ object from JS.
myclass.delete(); // Calls ~MyClass destructor in C++.

var myclass = Module.MyClass.CreateInstance(); //Creates a C++ object from C++ and returns to JS.
myclass.delete(); // Calls ~MyClass destructor in C++.
```

**In C++**

Your class is responsible for any internal dynamic memory created(using `new` operator). Dynamic memory created needs to be deleted in destructor. In your provided example you don't use dynamic memory, no need to delete any memory or create destructor.

The 3 `std::vector` (r,g and b) are created with the stack memory(no dynamic memory using new operator).

I suggest that your class the attributes need to be private and have getters to prevent external access.

```
class RGB {
private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> r;
    std::vector<unsigned char> g;
    std::vector<unsigned char> b;

public:
    RGB(const std::vector<unsigned char>& r_ = {}, 
        const std::vector<unsigned char>& g_ = {},
        const std::vector<unsigned char>& b_ = {})
        : r(r_), g(g_), b(b_)
    {
    }
    
    const std::vector<unsigned char>& getR() const {
        return r;
    }
    
    const std::vector<unsigned char>& getG() const {
        return g;
    }
    
    const std::vector<unsigned char>& getB() const {
        return b;
    }
};
```